# Enter digits into a masked input field in a free form format using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to build a form input using the mask plug-in that will change the characteristic of the entry for time to permit the user to enter digits in a free form format and the system will convert the entered digits into proper time display using jQuery.

**Example:** the user to enter “135” and the system to convert this to “01:35”

The code for the mask is:

```
$("input.time").mask("99:99");
```

So far I have the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#awareness-hour').blur(function() {
    if(!$('#awareness-hour').val().match(/([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/)){
        alert('invalid');           
    }else{
        return true;
    };
});
});
```

Comment: do you just want to zero-pad the left side when the length of the input entry is 3 as opposed to four?

Comment: Sure, if it validates in 24HR format.

Comment: I'm trying to help you, but I still don't understand what is it exactly that you want. I don't know about your mask plug-in but am looking at http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/. So you are saying if the user enters 13:5_ into your 99:99 mask, you want to accept this as 01:35? If so, what's the value you obtain from the mask plug-in for this case, 135 or "13:5"? Are you wanting to update the input? I want to understand better which portion you are struggling with. What value do you have upon your mask plugin doing its thing and what

Comment: Thanks cbayram for your time! Your assumption is correct when you ask, "if the user inputs 13:5_ then the field will change to 01:35".

This should be triggered when they leave that particular field. My client wants the mask for visual appeal.

Is there a way to achieve the same result without the mask plug-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will correct the scenario you mentioned and update the input only if it's a valid time according to your second regular expression. Hopefully, you get the idea and this works:

```
$("input.time").blur(function() {       
    var userInput = $(this).val().replace(/^([0-9])([0-9]):([0-9])_$/, "0$1:$2$3");     
    if(!userInput.match(/([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/)){
        alert('invalid');           
    }else{
        $(this).val(userInput);
        return true;
    };
}).mask("99:99");
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I owe you a virtual beer